# Does every class in symfony2 need to be a service?

Tags: symfony, oop, design-patterns

Intro moved to the bottom:

Right now I'm working on a small system, that manages orders and products.
I'm trying to refactor chunks of code from the controller and into business and service classes, here's what I'm trying to pull

```
/src/domain/bundle/Business/
/src/domain/bundle/Services/
```

So in the Business, I will have an `Order` Class, that does some calculations, some of these calculations required data from the database (on the fly).

Here's exactly the problem I have:

1. The controller loads an array of Orders that needs processing
2. The controller sends orders that needs processing to the `OrderBusiness` class
3. The `OrderBusiness` class needs to get the product(s) price from the database

Now I'm stuck..
What I'm attempting to do, is I made a `ProductsService` class, that returns the required product and price from the database, but how can I call this class from my `OrderBusiness` class without defining my `OrderBusiness` class as a service and injecting it with the `ProductsService` class

Intro:

I'm quiet sorry if my questions seems to be a little general and ignorant.
I've been using Symfony2 for less than a year now, and some things I can't wrap my mind around, even after reading the documentations, and a lot of the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do whatever you want but it's often better to stick to Symfony's default way:

1. Controller gets data from request, validates it, calls other classes, and renders request (usually using Twig or `JsonResponse::create`).
2. To get data from database there are repositories. It's good when they return plain old PHP objects (POPO). Usually are managed with Doctrine magic.
3. To process objects (aggregate, filter, connect to external services, etc) you can create services. You don't to suffix them with `Service` (any class name is OK) and put to `Service` folder.

When you create many simple classes that follow "Single responsibility principle" it's convenient to connect them with dependency injection. Then your classes don't stick to each other too much and it's easy to swap one class with another without changing code in all files, also good for testing.

Comment: Thank you, generally speaking sounds great, but when you need to reach out for data (through repositories), you need access that repo, so you have to inject it, so you have to define it as a service. And I don't like suffixing classes with Service, but worst is using the same class name in different folders.

Comment: You don't have to inject repository, you can inject EntityManger and get repository from it `$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')`. And try to name classes so that new guy (or you in 6 months) understands what class does without looking into the code. What does `OrderBusiness`? Did you mean `OrderPriceCalculator`? If it does several things and hard to name, may be it's time to split it to `PriceCalculator` and `OrderDelivery`, etc.

Comment: sorry @luchaninov , that's what I actually do

Answer (score 1):

#### Symfony: Dependency Injection

So, Symfony not requirements for define all classes as services! The service layer - [DependencyInjection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html)

1. You must register a new service in container for access to this service in another systems/services/business logic. Performance for this: the service will be created (`new SomeService`) only one time, and cache this object in inner cache layer.
2. If you want create a new service instance for each time, you can add `scope: prototype` to [service definition](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#understanding-scopes)
3. This system vary good for many references between services.

#### You problem/solution:

In best practices - in no way!

As solution: you can use singlton, or use static services.

But, i recommend use dependency injection pattern layer for this problem and create all classes for each logic. Reasons:

1. Single responsibility
2. Easy testing with PHPSpec/PHPUnit (because each class - one business logic).
3. You can inject common logic in `__constructor` without parameters `$this->dependencyService = new SomeService()`!
4. If you not want define service in container, but another service have reference, you can define dependency service as [private](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#marking-services-as-public-private) `public: false`
5. Dynamical services (creates via factory) for any condition (request, user, scope, etc...)

#### In my case:

As example from my another project (Orders, Products, Variants...)

I have:

1. `ProductRepository` - for load products, variants.
2. `PriceCalculator` - for calculate price for product (I loads price from product property, but you can inject `PriceLoader` service for loads prices from another storages).
3. `OrderProcessor` - for processing order.

**Controller:**

```
class OrderProcessingController
{
    private $productRepository;
    private $orderProcessor;

    public function __construct($productRepository, $orderProcessor)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->orderProcessor = $orderProcessor;
    }

    public function processForProduct($product)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->find($productId = $product);

        if (!$product) {
            // Control for product not found
        }

        $this->orderProcessor->processForProduct($product);

        return new Response('some html');
    }
}
```

In this we only load product, control if not found and call to process. Vary simple and easy testing.

**Order processor:**

```
class OrderProcessor
{
    private $priceCalculator;
    private $priceLoader;

    public function __construct($priceCalculator, $priceLoader)
    {
        $this->priceCalculator = $priceCalculator;
        $this->priceLoader = $priceLoader;
    }

    public function processForProduct($product)
    {
        $price = $this->priceLoader->loadForProduct($product);
        $price = $this->priceCalculator->calculateForProduct($price, $product);

        // Some processing

        return $order;
    }
}
```

In this class - we load price for product, calculate, create order and call to another processing if necessary. Vary simple and easy testing.

#### P.S.

> Right now I'm working on a small system, that manages orders and products.

Can use any microframework? [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) as example or [Symfony Microframework](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-symfony-as-a-microframework), and completely unsubscribe from dependency injection layer?

Comment: Thank you, and this is very similar to what I had at the beginning, but as we move forward, and more requirements come, you want to process a list of Orders. So you have a different set of classes, and 2 levels you find you need to get more data, so this class needs to be a Service, which put me off a bit

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'm stuck.. What I'm attempting to do, is I made a ProductsService
>   class, that returns the required product and price from the database,

Use repository class for business queries. Don't mix application layers. You can also define the repository as a service.

When class represents the general interface or represents an algorithm (e.g. business) define it as service.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing, and since I depend a lot on the database, than almost all of my classes are services.